# google maps api marker zoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps, zooming

I enter the coordinates of antwerp in my JavaScript code to place a marker on the map , but when I test it in my browser it places a marker in the middle of the map and if I zoom in it becomes more accurate until the marker is at the right place ... what am I doing wrong ??
The marker is not at the right place when zoomed out but it is when I zoom in. thanks in advance!

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.2239721,4.413785),
      zoom: 8
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.2239721,4.413785);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title:"ap hogeschool"
});
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: [works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=antwerp&geocode=1) (although the coordinates I get for antwerp are 51.219448,4.402464).  [Fiddle with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/rfgA7/). Are you using custom markers?

Comment: @geocodezip I use exactly the same code as yours , but my marker still isnt accurate at all ! i'm not using a custom markers.

Comment: Can you provide an example (a fiddle like I did) that exhibits the problem?

Comment: strange ... in fiddle it seems to work (http://jsfiddle.net/nicker/VSvLN/)

Comment: Then the problem is elsewhere in your environment (css maybe?)

Comment: That was the problem ! i removed my css file and now it works ! thanks a lot man !

Answer (score 0):

You can use google map latlngBounds as the code below will do that. u may need to read this
[here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#LatLngBounds)

```
var locBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        locBounds.extend(LatLng1);
        locBounds.extend(latlng2);

        map.fitBounds(locBounds);
```